# How to use "either" with negating "no"?

Tags: conjunctions, negation

The following text is a translation from a medical ultrasonography test result:

> No hydronephrosis was observed in either kidney.

Given the fact that "No" is used to negate the sentence, I am skeptic of the correctness of using "either" in the above sentence. If it is wrong, then should "neither" be used instead?

Answer (score 3):

The above statement is absolutely right.

> No hydronephrosis was observed in either kidney.

Here, you are negating the statement about *hydronephrosis being present in at least one of the kidneys* (either).

Or if you are so keen on avoiding 'either' and using 'neither' instead, you can use the following:

> Neither of the kidneys was observed to have hydronephrosis.

This just makes it very complex for understanding and having said it is a medical report, better to avoid such complexity.

Comment: In your latter example, I would prefer ["Neither ... was ..." vs. "... were ..."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are).

Comment: @shoover I have changed it now. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is correct, using 'neither' would make it a double negative (which has the effect of making the sentence affirmative in a really ugly and clumsy way):

> No hydronephrosis was observed in neither kidney

Means: "Neither kidney had no hydronephrosis -> They both had hydronephrosis"

> No hydronephrosis was observed in either kidney

"We checked the first kidney for hydronephrosis, there was none. Then we checked the second, there was no hydronephrosis in that one either."